# Can't get ng-repeat to work in angularjs with array in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below is my code. Not sure why ng-repeat shows up completely blank.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Larry

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
     </script>
     <body>

         <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <ul><li ngrepeat="x in names">{{x}}</li></ul> </div>

<script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.names = ["Emil","Tobias","Linus"];
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it should be: `ng-repeat`

Comment: ngrepeat was a typo.  The actual code is ng-repeat

Comment: Works just fine when the typo is fixed. http://plnkr.co/edit/ea7zpWCw9AnqXCrqbxtB?p=preview. Post a complete example reproducing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the typo

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"> </script>
  <body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <ul><li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</li></ul> </div>
<script>
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.names = ["Emil","Tobias","Linus"];
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Lary G. Can you accept the answer. So the question will be closed